# how to implement hint to my search box like google and other search engines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a search engine type website. It needs some hints for the users just like google and other search engines provide. Please someone tell me the most optimal way to do that

Comment: Can use `auto complete`..?

Comment: Please elaborate it what you said @Gautam3164

Comment: Optimal as in quickest to implement, or the most flexibility and performance? If you care about building one yourself I can show you how to build it in plain JavaScript. Otherwise go with a plugin.

Comment: You are making `search engine` type website,so you can use auto complete the things those you are allowing to search by users

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `autocomplete jquery` to do so...
try this `chosen jquery library` I also use the same in my application...

http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

also check this..

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang", 
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

Put this code ... You need to create an `array` to get the `autocomplete` work.. **it doesnt have his own mind to think for suggestion**

refrence from jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @hisham check my edited answer.. and if you liked it than please chose as correct... thanks :)

Comment: i am applying it in my search box (which is input type text) but no hints are coming

Comment: <input class="search-term required" type="text" id="search" name="search" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" onkeyup="validation()" placeholder="Type your search terms here" title="* Please enter a search term!" autocomplete="off" required>                  I am applying it in this textbox by using the id search

Comment: not possible using this.. I am providing you the whole code please check my edit..

Comment: i want to get the data from the database

Comment: `$qry = mysql_query('select * from table_name');
$ans = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$ans .= "'".$row['suggestion']."',";
}`

and use this $ans variable in javascript like..

`var availableTags = [+"<?php echo $ans ?>"+];`

Comment: its not working ,hints are not coming but the variable $ans is getting all the values,when i echoed it

Comment: try `alerting` `availabletags` in javascript.. check which value it contains

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for suggestions from DB when user types something in the text box then you can look at this URL: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_database.asp